# Usage of cursorY in Charting?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

When using system.windows.forms.datavisualization.Charting, I am able to zoom the xAxis by click and dragging the left-mouse. But, I don't seem to be able to zoom the yAxis. I see a y cursor, but I can't select or move it.

This is the basic set-up:

```
    chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Your code works just fine here, I can zoom in either direction. Note that you don't select a cursor. It is a tool that shows the mouse position better.

Comment: @TaW When you select does a scollbar appear on yAxis? That only happens on xAxis for me...

Comment: Yes it does appear. At least when the mouse move not strictly horizontally. anything special about the y-values? Minima, maxima?

Comment: I tried fixing and unfixing the values for max and min, but it makes no difference

Comment: @TaW Found it! It was the interval. My y range was 0.5 to 1.5, but interval was 1. So I guess it could not put cursor anywhere else...